# Unable to persist complex entity graph in Symfony2/Doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm a bit limited in the details I can provide due to a NDA, so please bear with me.

I have a complex entity graph. It consists of:

- A 1-to-1 relationship between a `Parent` and `Child`.
- The `Child` contains an `ArrayCollection` of `FooChild` entities.  Cascade all.
- `FooChild` represents a many-to-many join table between `Foo` and `Child`, but also contains some metadata that `Child` needs to track.  Cascade persist on each side (`Foo` and `Child`)
- `Parent`s aren't required to have a `Child`.

To be 100% clear regarding `FooChild`, the relationship is many-to-many, but because of the metadata, it contains many-to-one relationship definitions:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="foo_children", indexes={
 *      @ORM\Index(name="fooid_idx", columns={"foo_id"}),
 *      @ORM\Index(name="childid_idx", columns={"child_id"}),
 * })
 */

class FooChild
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Foo", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="foo_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $foo;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Child", inversedBy="fooChildren", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="child_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $child;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
     */
    private $count;

    // methods
}
```

Okay, so with that structure, on the `Parent` edit page, I created the option for someone to add a `Child` to it and populate it with `FooChild`s with the Symfony prototype mechanism seen [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype).  When I attempt to submit the rather large form, I get the following exception:

> Entity of type MyBundle\Entity\FooChild has identity through a foreign entity MyBundle\Entity\Child, however this entity has no identity itself. You have to call EntityManager#persist() on the related entity and make sure that an identifier was generated before trying to persist 'MyBundle\Entity\FooChild'. In case of Post Insert ID Generation (such as MySQL Auto-Increment or PostgreSQL SERIAL) this means you have to call EntityManager#flush() between both persist operations.

The thing is, I've attempted to persist the various parts of this graph in different orders, and the exception still remains.  My current attempt is:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ParentType(), $parent);

if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->has('child')) {
        $data = $form->getData();
        $child = $data->getChild();
        $fooChildren = $child->getFooChildren();

        foreach ($fooChildren as $fc) {
            $em->persist($fc);
            $em->flush();
        }

        $em->persist($child);
        $em->flush();
    }

    $em->persist($parent);
    $em->flush();
}
```

The exception is thrown at the first attempt to persist, in the foreach.  Like I said before, I've swapped the order of what gets persisted when several times, but it hasn't made a difference.  I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Are you sure that the variables you are passing to your persist method are indeed instances of the entities? In your `foreach` what is the output of `print gettype($fc)` and if it is `object` what is the output of  `print get_class($fc);`

Comment: Yes, they are instances of my entities.  The PhpStorm debugger verifies.  I can't post a screen shot without violating the NDA.

Comment: did you try to persist & flush the `$parent` then `$child` then `$fooChildren` ?

Comment: I think you need to remove the `$child` from the `$parent` then persist and flush the `$parent` since it doesn't require a child, and do the same with `$child` and `$fooChildren` not optimal but might be a good start to see what exactly causing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an initial solution of removing the `Child`'s form type and having the `Parent`'s form type handle unmapped (very important) `FooChild` entries.  Then, in the controller, I had:

```
$em->persist($parent);
$em->flush();

if ($form->has('fooChildren')) {
    $child = new Child();
    $child->setParent($parent);

    $em->persist($child);
    $em->flush();

    // run through the FooChild entites and add them to the child
}
```

It worked, but I ran into some other non-related issues, so I'm currently reorganizing my schema.